# How to level up speed in a game made with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I made a game for a project with javascript (here's the link : https://cams03.github.io/canvus/page_accueil.html)

Now I'd like to improve the game by increasing the speed of the flying objects. I've tried many things and there's always a problem. Here's the sample of my code (if needed I can provide the full code but it's quite longer). The variable cpt is the score

```
let planetTimer2, planetTimer3, planetTimer4;

function level() {
 if (cpt == 5 ) {
    clearInterval(planetTimer);
    planetTimer2 = setInterval(spawnPlanet, 1000);
 }
 if (cpt == 20) {
    clearInterval(planetTimer2);
    planetTimer3 = setInterval(spawnPlanet, 0700);
 }
 if (cpt == 40) {
    clearInterval(planetTimer3);
    planetTimer4 = setInterval(spawnPlanet, 0500);
 }
}

function countdown() {

 level();   

 if (timeLeft < 0) {
     clearTimeout(timerId);
     clearTimeout(planetTimer);
     clearTimeout(planetTimer2);
     clearTimeout(planetTimer3);
     clearTimeout(planetTimer4);
     clearTimeout(bonusTimer);
     let paragraph = document.getElementById("result");
     if (cpt < 20) {
         paragraph.innerHTML = "Ton score est de : " + cpt + ". La       honte sur toi Maurice !!";
     } else if (cpt < 80) {
         paragraph.innerHTML = "Mouais ton score est de : " + cpt + ". Tu peux faire mieux mon vieux !";
     } else {
         paragraph.innerHTML = "Ton score est de : " + cpt + ". T'es un killer !!";
     }

     document.querySelector("h1").appendChild(paragraph);
     cover.classList.add("visible");
     popup.classList.add("visible");

 } else {
     timer.innerHTML = timeLeft;
     timeLeft--;
 }   

 };

let timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", countdown());

rejouer.addEventListener("click", function () {
  cover.classList.remove("visible");
  popup.classList.remove("visible");
  cpt = 0;
  timeLeft = 30;
  countdown();
  timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  spawnPlanet();
  spawnBonus();
  planetTimer = setInterval(spawnPlanet, 2000);
  bonusTimer = setInterval(spawnBonus, 9000);


 });
```

The thing is that `if (cpt == 5 )` can't be used because if you catch a bonus your score can increase from 3 to 7 (for example) without passing by 5 so the equality won't exist and the condition won't be executed. 
Anyone can help me please ? I hope that my explanations are clear, thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: First of all, don't prefix your numbers with `0`. That makes JavaScript think they're hexadecimal numbers. See for yourself: `console.log(0700, 700)`

Comment: Your use of `0700` and `0500` seems suspicious.  Did you try using `700` and `500` instead?

Comment: No I didn't know that I can use 700, I learnt to write 0700 but it is probably the wrong way, I'm going to correct it thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This should be relatively simple to fix.

Check if the score is equal to, or greater than the score to compare it to (5, 20, 40), and check if the timer is still running.

After a clearinterval, also unset the timer variables.

```
function level() {
 if (cpt >= 5 && planetTimer) {
    clearInterval(planetTimer);
    delete planetTimer;
    planetTimer2 = setInterval(spawnPlanet, 1000);
 }
 if (cpt >= 20 && planetTimer2) {
    clearInterval(planetTimer2);
    delete planetTimer2;
    planetTimer3 = setInterval(spawnPlanet, 700);
 }
 if (cpt >= 40 && planetTimer3) {
    clearInterval(planetTimer3);
    delete planetTimer3;
    planetTimer4 = setInterval(spawnPlanet, 500);
 }
}
```

---

Also, in `function countdown()`, you have a couple of `clearTimeout` calls. Those should be `clearInterval`.

Comment: Ok thank you ! I'm going to try to change the code now and see if it works. Actually I tried the condition with && but it was `if (cpt>=5 && cpt <=20)` and it didn't work

Comment: I tried the code and when I hit 5 it seems to work at first, then planets are popping everywhere and don't disappear, so I have like 20 planets on the screen. I don't know why, it seems that the clearInterval or clearTimeOut doesn't work. Moreover, when the window with the final score appears the spawnPlanet function doesn't stop and planets keep popping. Do you know how to fix it ? Maybe I shouldn't use multiple variables like planetTimer2, planetTimer3 etc.. and only change the planetTimer ?